# Very elementary TypeError in Django

Tags: django

I'm following all of the instructions in this tutorial, time 2:26
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqRLPx4ZeSw&t=3s
and I cannot get the expected result. The TypeError I'm getting is

`raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().`

**File: urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/$', 'posts.views.post_home'),
    # url(r'^posts/$', '<appname>.views.post_home'),
]
```

**File: views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def post_home(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello</h1>")
```

And here are the relevant screenshots, however I cannot post them because the computer thinks that they're code.  Because it thinks they're code when I hit cntrl k the screenshots go away, but if I do not hit cntrl k, then I cannot post the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this for your code to work:

```
from posts import views as posts_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/$', posts_views.post_home),
]
```

But it's best you use `include` to append the app urls, you have to create an 
`urls.py` in your posts app.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

url(r'^posts/', include('posts.urls')),
```